# ASP.Net Core you must add reference to System.Runtime Version 4.1.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm having a bizarre issue.  I have a T4 Generator which is generating templates.
Everything Generates fine until I try to reference `MyType.GetCustomAttributes<MyAttributeAttribute>(false).SingleOrDefault();`

Then I receive an error:

> Compiling transformation: The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. RestEzApiCore

This is definitely referenced, it seems to be a mismatch between framework types.

I'm running on VS2017, maybe adding a runtime policy might help, but I don't know how to

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

**EDIT**

Here are a list of things I've tried which have not worked:

1. I've wiped my packages folder clean
2. installing .Net-Framework 1.6 which has not helped me.
3. Moving All the Runtime Code to a seperate DLL
4. I deleted all project including the prior .net 4.5.2 and Upgraded them all to ASP.Net-Core

None of these options have seemed to work

Comment: have you resharper installed

Comment: I don't have resharper

Comment: try to  update visual studio to latest version

Comment: Thanks, but I'm running the latest

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem after installing the Power BI embedded ASP.NET nuget package. I worked in my development environment, but not in production. In many postings, the advice is to install .net SDK, but I found another way:

Install the System.Runtime NuGet package (with the version you need). Then, add a reference in WebConfig (change Version and key according to your needs):

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

I hope you can get some inspiration from my solution.